# NativeAdsExpress forces RecyclerView to Scroll to have the NativeAd fully visible when first loaded

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview, native-ads

I have a weird "problem" or may be it's a "feature" and I just don't know, whenever a NativeAdExpress is loaded in my RecyclerView if only part of the NativeAd is visible, it forces the RecyclerView to scroll until the Native ad becomes fully visible, this behavior causes the list to keep jumping as I scroll.

My Layout is mainly:

Activity > AppBar with Tabs and ViewPager > each Page in the Pager contains PullToRefresh and inside it there's a RecyclerView,
The RecyclerView has 2 types of items (Article and NativeAdExpress).

**UPDATE: My guess on why this is happening is mainly because native ads express render in a webview, and this webview receives focus then this causes the RecyclerView to scroll to it, but that's only a Guess**

**UPDATE 2: Apparently this is an issue in Support Lib. 24.0.0, that's the cost of being too up2date :(**

Heres's my Full XML/Layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my.package.custom.views.CustomDrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light"
        fontPath="fonts/fonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="5px"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/contentColor"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_item_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavDrawerStyle"
        tools:openDrawer="end"
        />

</my.package.custom.views.CustomDrawerLayout>
```

where  "app_bar_main.xml" is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.ArticlesListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="end"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:paddingStart="14dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ivCustomDrawable"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:tint="@color/white"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/view_title"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    style="@style/SectionTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/sources_spinner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:transitionName="@string/transition_splash_logo"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/TabsStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:transitionGroup="true"
            app:tabContentStart="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.RegularTextFont"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context=".ui.activities.ArticlesListActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_newsitem_list">

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/viewpager"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and finally I have 2 View Types  Item and NativeAdExpress:

The NativeAdExpress ViewHolder is as follows:

```
public class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends BaseCardAdViewHolder {
    private final NativeExpressAdView view;
    private boolean loaded = false;
    private AdListener adListener;
    private WeakReference<Context> context;

    public NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View itemView, String adId, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        view = new NativeExpressAdView(context);
        view.setAdUnitId(adId);
        ((LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.express_ad_holder)).addView(view);
        this.context = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    public void loadAd(float cardWidthInDips) {
        if (!loaded && null != context.get() && !view.isLoading()) {
            int width = cardWidthInDips > 0 ? (int) cardWidthInDips : 330;
            if (view.getAdSize() == null) {
                view.setAdSize(new AdSize(width, 330));
                view.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        super.onAdLoaded();
                        loaded = true;
                        if (adListener != null) {
                            adListener.onAdLoaded();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                        if (adListener != null) {
                            adListener.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdOpened() {
                        super.onAdOpened();
                        if (adListener != null) {
                            adListener.onAdOpened();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            new Handler(context.get().getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public NativeExpressAdView getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setAdListener(AdListener adListener) {
        this.adListener = adListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyAd() {
        if (view != null) {
            view.destroy();
            loaded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and ads are create using a custom adapter as follows:

```
private BaseCardViewHolder createNativeExpressAdViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_express, parent, false);
        final NativeExpressAdViewHolder viewHolder = new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(
            view,
            adManager.getNativeExpressAdId(),
            context.get()
        );
        adViewHolders.add(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Log.i("ADS", "onAdFailedToLoad " + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                // Do something
            }
        });
        viewHolder.loadAd(cardWidthInDips);

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did not understand where you actually implement a `RecyclerView` in your code but here is anyway maybe something that could work in your case.

I had a similar problem with a `GridView` always getting the focus during a `Fragment` first load, it was also automatically scrolling down straight to the `GridView`.

After a lot of tests, I finally stopped this behavior with this one line on the parent layout of the `GridView`:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

This line basically means that all descendants from the parent layout will not get focus anymore. You can try it out on your `RecyclerView` parent layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the job, though I have to say that this issue in general affects only "some" version of android support lib. e.g. 23.4.0 is not affect while 23.2.x and 23.3.0 and 24.0.0 are affected by this issue!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's an *issue*, but the it looks like RecyclerView changed its behavior somewhere from support library 23.4.0 to 24.2.0.

Now instead of defaulting to descendantFocusability = beforeDescendants, it defaults to afterDescendants, which causes it to offer the focus to their children instead of taking it for itself.

When a child takes the focus, it ends up scrolling to make it visible.

I fixed it by adding android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" to the RecyclerView, to recover the previous behavior, where it keeps the focus itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with RecyclerView scrolling, not specifically to NativeAdExpress...but there seems to be an issue with the *Android Support library* <s>**24.0.0**</s> related to this. The <s>android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"</s> didn't work for me. But downgrading to *Android Support library* **23.4.0** made it start working again.